# Winsock IOCP Server Stress Test Issue

Tags: c++, client, winsock, iocp

I have a winsock IOCP server written in c++ using TCP IP connections.  I have tested this server locally, using the loopback address with a client simulator.  I have been able to get upwards of 60,000 clients no sweat.  The issue I am having, is when I run the server at my house and the client simulator at a friends house.  Everything works fine up until we hit around 3700 connections, after that every call to connect() fails from the client side with a return of 10060 (this is the winsock timed out error).  Last night this number was 3700, but it has been around 300 before, and we also saw it near 1000.  But whatever the number is, every time we try to simulate it, it will fail right around that number (within 10 or so).

Both computers are using Windows 7 Ultimate.  We have also both modified the TCPIP registry setting MaxTcpConnections to around 16 million.  We also changed the MaxUserPort setting from its 5000 default to 65k.  No useful information is showing up in the event viewer.  We also both watched our resource monitor, and we havent even gotten to 1% network utilization, the CPU is also close to 0% usage as well.

We just got off the phone with our ISP, and they are saying that they are not limiting us in any way but the guy was kinda unsure and ended up hanging up on us anyway after a 30 minute hold time...

We are trying everything to figure this issue out, but cannot come up with the solution.  I would be very greatful if someone out there could give us a hand with this issue.

P.S. Both computers are on Verizon FIOS with the same verizon router.  Another thing to note, the server is using WSAAccept and NOT AcceptEx.  The client simulator is attempting to connect over many seconds though, so I am pretty sure the connects are not getting backlogged.  We have tried to change the speed at which the client simulator connects, and no matter what speed it is set to it fails right around the same number each time.

UPDATE
We simulated 2 separate clients (on 2 separate machines) on network A.  The server was running on network B.  Each client was only able to connect half (about 1600) connections to the server.  We were initially using a port below 1,000, this has been changed to above 50,000.  The router log on both machines showed nothing.  We are both using the Actiontec MI424WR verizon FIOS router.  This leads me to believe the problem is not with the client code.  The server throws no errors and has no unexpected behavior.  Could this be an ISP/Router issue?

UPDATE
The solution has been found.  The verizon router we were using (MI424WR revision C) is unable to handle any more than 3700 connections, we tested this with a separate set of networks.  Thanks for the help guys!

Thanks
- Rick

Comment: Try using a packet sniffer (eg. wireshark) to determine the problem

Comment: Ill download it and give it a try, I havent used one before so I am not sure what exactly to look for.  Does it show you errors that are occuring, or do I just have to examine low level packets and determine for myself what is happening?

Answer (score 0):

I would have guessed that this was a MaxUserPort issue, but you say you've changed that. Did you reboot after changing it?

Run the test on the exact same computers on your local network (this will take the computers out of the equation).

The issue could be one of your routers not being up to the job?

Comment: Thanks for the response.  Yea we both rebooted and have been dealing with this issue over the past few days.  I have not ran the test over the local network yet, I will see if I can do this and let you know what happens.

Comment: Also, what exactly can the router do to prevent this code from working (where would it fail?)

Comment: I'd be surprised if it were the router, but perhaps, if it's a cheap home router, it's not able to deal with that many concurrent connections...

Comment: You could try using my test tool which is linked to from here: http://www.serverframework.com/asynchronousevents/2010/10/how-to-support-10000-or-more-concurrent-tcp-connections---part-2---perf-tests-from-day-0.html this would take your client code out of the equation.

Comment: Thanks, this sounds great.  I will download it when I get home and see if I can come to any conclusions.  I was reading your site before and you seem pretty knowledgable when it comes to large scale networking.  So I must ask, are there any other registry keys that you needed to modify for your systems, are you using a server version of windows?  Have you supported a large client base with windows 7?

Comment: MaxUserPort is the only tuning that's needed and then only for machines where you intend to create lots of client connections.